# Git graphical history output

Tags: git

Currently I'm using `git log --graph --all` to visualize my repo's history

I'd like the output to also contain the branch for which the commit was done on. How would i do this?

Current Output:

```
* | commit 2da166d419c48555b1ce79784304632bf3f6e98f
| | Author: TechplexEngineer <techplex.engineer@>
| | Date:   Fri Jul 6 10:53:55 2012 -0400
| |
| |     Changed polled and exception mode to use the same logic to decide when t
| |     do a refresh/poll.
| |
* | commit b2b7a99931a917e697da3bc38be1636b33c1c44a
|/  Author: TechplexEngineer <techplex.engineer@>
|   Date:   Thu Jul 5 14:43:38 2012 -0400
|
|       Cleaned up comments and removed some old dead code
|
| * commit fb6d01eafca28aa3a84e72ed3f057486accd6532
|/  Author: cparent <Christopher.Parent@>
|   Date:   Fri Jul 6 10:38:28 2012 -0400
|
|       Got multiple reads and writes to happen in both
|       polled and exception mode
```

Desired Output:

```
* | commit 2da166d419c48555b1ce79784304632bf3f6e98f on branch Master
| | Author: TechplexEngineer <techplex.engineer@>
| | Date:   Fri Jul 6 10:53:55 2012 -0400
| |
| |     Changed polled and exception mode to use the same logic to decide when t
| |     do a refresh/poll.
| |
* | commit b2b7a99931a917e697da3bc38be1636b33c1c44a on branch Master
|/  Author: TechplexEngineer <techplex.engineer@>
|   Date:   Thu Jul 5 14:43:38 2012 -0400
|
|       Cleaned up comments and removed some old dead code
|
| * commit fb6d01eafca28aa3a84e72ed3f057486accd6532 on branch chris
|/  Author: cparent <Christopher.Parent@>
|   Date:   Fri Jul 6 10:38:28 2012 -0400
|
|       Got multiple reads and writes to happen in both
|       polled and exception mode
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible because the original branch (if any) on which a commit was made is not recorded by git.

Using `--decorate` which will annotate commits if they are currently pointed to by a branch or tag is about the best that you can get.

Comment: Thanks, this works: `git log --graph --decorate --all --date=relative`

Answer (score 0):

That’s not really possible as branches are just *pointers* to a single commit. As such a commit can be part of the history of many different branches. At best you can get something similar to gitk’s output where the branch or tag is simply a marker next to a commit.